# How to install Pyaudio in python 3.11.1?

Tags: python, macos, installation, artificial-intelligence, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio but it always says like this: [Python 3.11.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkAZ3.jpg). I am trying to make AI and using macos.

Try to help me to install pyaudio in the macos

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

You need portaudio installed.  If you're using Homebrew, you can do it with this command:

```
brew install portaudio
```

Comment: I already did like that but when I tried to do this command: pip install pyaudio. It says error

Answer (score 0):

To install `pyaudio` on your mac. First, you will need `portaudio` installed. That can be done using `brew`. If you don't have brew installed follow [this link](https://brew.sh/) to install `brew` on your mac.

```
brew install portaudio
```

After installing `portaudio` you can install pyaudio using pip.

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: What makes you think OP is using Anaconda?

Comment: it said command not found: conda

Comment: If you don't have conda installed please use pip. I have updated my answer.